# C++ OpenMP program

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to get a parallel effect in C++ program using the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

#pragma omp parallel sections
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
        cout<<"Hello";  
        cout<<" ";  
        cout<<"World";  
        cout<<endl;

        }
#pragma omp section
        {
        cout<<"H";
        cout<<"ello";
        cout<<" W";
        cout<<"orld";
        cout<<endl;
        }
#pragma omp section
        cout<<"Hello"<<" "<<"World"<<endl;
#pragma omp section
{       cout<<"Hello ";
        cout<<"World"<<endl;
}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I had run this program many times.. I was expecting interleaved output due to parallelism..

However, every time I run this program the output is:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How many cores/processors your machine actually has?

Comment: 4 cores... And what if I want to see the effect on only one core?

Comment: unless your CPU does hyperthreading, *there is no effect* on only one core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct, but interleaved output can be hard to get from such small programs. Try putting some calls to `sleep` or similar between output statements and do some flushing.

(Did you compile and link with `-openmp`, `-fopenmp`, or whatever your compiler want to hear?)

Answer (score 4):

How have you compiled the program? Is OpenMP activated?

Apart from that, a much simpler Hello World looks like this, if you want to get interleaving characters:

```
int main() {
    char const* str = "Hello world";
    unsigned const len = std::strlen(str);
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (unsigned thread = 0; thread < 4; ++thread)
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;
}
```